# Moderately minify HTML (from Beautiful Soup output)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Beautiful soup smears out HTML so that every element starts a new line.

All the HTML minifiers I have found compress everything to a single line.

Is there, somewhere (and preferably in Python) a tool that will output normal HTML. That is: block elements would get a new line, but inline elements would not?

**BS output**

```
<h2>
 headline
</h2>
<p>
  Blah blah
   <b>
     bold text
   </b>
  same paragraph blah
   <a href="">
     a link in the text
   </a>
</p>
<p>
 Another paragraph
</p>
```

**minified**

```
<h2>headline</h2><p> Blah blah <b> bold text </b> same paragraph blah <a href=""> a link in the text </a></p><p> Another paragraph</p>
```

**what i want**

```
<h2>headline</h2>
<p> Blah blah <b> bold text </b> same paragraph blah <a href=""> a link in the text </a></p>
<p> Another paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution.

Make a regex of the opening tags of each block level element.  Use `str()` on the BeautifulSoup tree, then use `re.sub()` to insert a \n in front of the block level elements.

```
import re

blocktags = '''\
<address    <article    <aside
<blockquote
<canvas
<dd    <div    <dl
<fieldset    <figcaption    <figure    <footer    <form
<h1    <h2    <h3    <h4    <h5    <h6    <header    <hgroup    <hr
<li
<main
<nav    <noscript
<ol    <output
<p    <pre
<section
<table    <tfoot
<ul
<video'''.split()

pat = re.compile('(' + '|'.join(blocktags) + ')')

blocked_str = pat.sub(r'\n\1', str(soup))
```

Comment: So I combined your solution with htmlmin (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/htmlmin/) instead of BS4's str(). (I need BS4's normal output because of character encoding and some other things.) Works.

Comment: The evil lord is coming after you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags